# Set Telegram bot webhook with multipart/form-data and allowed_updates

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Not so long ago Telegram Bot API got updated with new features for webhook configuration. One of them is `allowed_updates` field which is array of strings.

It also has a possibility to set webhook with custom self signed certificate. You just need to post webhook configuration as `multipart/form-data`.

But how to post `allowed_updates` which is array of strings as `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

you can post the allowed_updates array of strings by

```
allowed_updates=["callback_query","inline_query"]
```

You can set List the types of updates you want your bot to receive.
here I set to only receive updates of these types:callback_query & inline_query

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR_API_TOKEN>/setwebhook?url=<HTTPS_url_to send_updates_to>&max_connections=20&allowed_updates=["callback_query","inline_query"]
```

Here complete list of available update types.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update

Answer (score 0):

```
function MrPHPBot($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".{token}."/".$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}


MrPHPBot('setWebhook',[ 'url'=>$url , 'certificate'=>new CURLFile(realpath("key.pem")) , 'allowed_updates'=> ['message', 'edited_channel_post','callback_query'] ]);
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation instead of just pasting the code snippet?